# How to extract a type argument

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

How can I implement the `GetTypeArg` type below? The goal is to get the `N`th generic type argument from `T`.

```
type GetTypeArg<T, N extends number> = _____ // How to implement this

type X<T = string> = {value: T}
type Y<T,M=number> = {value1: T, value2: M}

type TestX = GetTypeArg<X, 1> // This should be string because the first type argument of X defaults to string
type TestY1 = GetTypeArg<Y<unknown>, 1> // This should be unknown because the first type argument of Y is unknown
type TestY2 = GetTypeArg<Y<string[]>, 2> // This should be number because the second type argument of Y defaults to number
```

Comment: The logic here is not very clear. Why should the 3rd example return number?

Comment: Because the second generic of `Y` is defaults to `number`.

Comment: If that's the case, then why does the second example not return `number`? Doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: if the n is 1 return the first generic type and if the n is 2 return second.

Comment: FYI, you've misunderstood the term "generic type". In `Y<string[]>`, it is Y that's the generic type; `string[]` is its *type argument*.

Comment: Thanks, the edit makes things much clearer. I've taken the liberty of (hopefully) making it clearer that you don't

Comment: I strongly suspect you can't do this without knowing a fair bit about the structure of the type you're passing as `T`. For instance, I can make it work with the specific `X` and `Y` above (making a dodgy assumption about the order of the type arguments relative to the property names), but I doubt it can be generalized: https://tsplay.dev/w8YqAN

Comment: You'd have to find a general way to represent an *unspecified generic type with N type parameters* in TypeScript, which I don't think is possible.

Comment: This is impossible for multiple reasons. One reason is that `T` in `GetTypeArg<T, N>` is just a type and can't have type arguments. Types are not nominal so they don't "remember" the name you used for them.  Once you plug in, say, `Y<string[]>` for `T`, you're talking about `{value1: string[], value2: number}`, which has no type arguments.  Any connection to "`Y`" is lost (or incredibly fragile). There are more reasons why this won't work, but I don't know how many reasons you need. Does that fully address your question? If so I'll write up an answer; if not, what's missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's hard to prove a negative, but I strongly suspect you can't do this in the general case. To infer a type in `GetTypeArg`, you can use [`infer`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#inferring-within-conditional-types) in a conditional type, but remember that TypeScript's type system is *structural* (based on the shapes of types), not nominal (based on the names/identities of types), so you have to have a *shape* to use in the condition type's `extends` clause. But there's no shape to test against, in the general case.

That means that although we can make it work with that specific `X` and `Y` (and types with shapes like theirs, including the property names) if we make a fairly dodgy assumption about the order of type arguments relative to properties (see below), we can't *generalize* that to encompass any or all types you might use with it.

Here's the limited version making dodgy assumptions ([playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA4hwBVwQIICcDmAeBAaKAclBAB7AQB2AJgM5QCMUAPlAEzNQDMA9AFRQpqUGgHsoIilABmItFACGdALbyKIKACM0qgMYALCHUWaIAGxEB3AHQ2ovbgD4oAXgBQUD4WJlKtBu88AfigEb3JqOgBvADd5UwBXCAAuKABLCikIOQA1AF8AzyCobILCqBTQ0nC-GLjE+hT0zJz8sqKSto8UighorNKUoirfOlZS4MqfCKhahIgGtIysqAANenxYudZGpZaoYOzyqB6+tAGvYenOcZCwkZnN+p3m1fWoR4htxZeV1g26iCcZ7LPL7YpHE79QrdXpZADcrlcoEgqxwLmEwDQ6QwTmcDwBFXyyOgAE0cLgALLOCjxJQaLK4-FzBZ4d4Ar4U-JI5AhQzAFbouCIZDobArfD0JzcbghPSpOg0PQieKmKgmDFYigYEw6eTxGjQYAGaSpNA0YBQDCULKpHSLVZpBWY7GuaWeAB6gW5KIQfJJjDxQqQkFFWDJ8QoAGsKJYKA4JVKZQg5QqlSq1fSoBHo7GdXqDVAjdApKbzZbrVi7ekoCTHcJ4IWxNmYxYKK6ZR5Pd7oL7zST2IH4MHUJgw1hzZqMABtAC68bYidl8uEadV6ppdOW9N1+sNxoNOgkaqtPUr9try439LObs7XqAA)), just for completeness:

```typescript
type GetTypeArg<T, N extends 1 | 2 | 3/* And so on for as many branches as below... */> =
    N extends 1
    ? T extends {value: infer V}
        ? V
        : T extends {value1: infer V}
        ? V
        : never
    : N extends 2
    ? T extends {value1: infer X1, value2: infer V} ? V : never
    : N extends 3
    ? T extends {value1: infer X1, value2: infer X2, value3: infer V} ? V : never
    : never;

type X<T = string> = {value: T}
type Y<T,M=number> = {value1: T, value2: M}

type TestX = GetTypeArg<X, 1> // This should be string because the first generic in X is string
//   ^? type TextX = string
type TestY1 = GetTypeArg<Y<unknown>, 1> // This should be unknown because the first generic in Y is set to unknown
//   ^? type TextY1 = unknown
type TestY2 = GetTypeArg<Y<string[]>, 2> // This should be number because the second generic in Y is number
//   ^? type TestY2 = number
```

But that's quite specific to the types you've shown for `X` and `Y`.

Again, I strongly suspect the answer is "You can't do that."